# Developing new versions of my Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, version

I am a newbie in Android Studio stuff. I have already developed a version 1.0 of my app. However, I want to update it into a new version 2.0 without overwritting the previous one. What is the correct way to achieve this?

Should I duplicate the project and work in other folder? Should I specify to gradle that my version is not the same as before?

Sorry for the dumb question, but I got lost here.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Use GIT and make a new Branch

Comment: When you develop an app you generally use a versioning tool to have your all development history. It helps you to manage different versions, to roll back to previous stable state or to cancel your changes. Have a look at Git as suggested. (http://github.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Way 1:**
You can create a new **module** in the same project. Now add the module in **settings.gradle** in project path. In this case, you will have 2 modules, module-1 for version-1 and module-2 for version-2. Finally, whenever you compile select the module you want to compile.

**Way 2:**
Create Git remote repository and push your current project in master branch. Now create a new branch in the same repository and develop your project in new branch for version 2. You can retrieve your version-1 project from master branch.

**Way 2 is recommended** for better practice.